# Grails UI(plugin) dialog not firing the controller action

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

Happy new year to all,

I am working on a project where I have to show the details of each record in the "list" in a dialog (modal window) window while the user click the link on each record in the list. I am trying to accomplish this using the GrailUI plugin. Here is my code:

```
<gui:dialog width="300px" 
           controller="tag" 
           action="showTags" 
           params=" [id:userInstance.userId]" 
           update="dialogData" 
           draggable="true" 
           triggers="[show:[type:'link', text:'Show Tags', on:'click']]" 
           modal="true">
   <div id='dialogData'>This will be updated by the controller action....</div>
```

For some reason the dialog tag is not firing the controller action. It opens the dialog window, but shows just this message "This will be updated by the controller action....". It's not showing the controller action rendered output(view). Could someone help me to understand what I am doing wrong?

Jquery and jquery-ui are the other plugins I am using in my project.

Appreciate your help.

**Edit**

```
     def test(Integer max) {
        ....
        ....
        userInstanceList = User.list(params)
        render (view: "test", model: [userInstanceList: userInstanceList, userInstanceTotal: User.count()])

}           

def showTags () {
    def user = User.findByUserId(params.id)
        def tagInstanceList = user.tags
    render(view: "test", model: [tagInstanceList: tagInstanceList])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want something be submit to remote you need to set `form="true"`. Then any form elements can be placed inside the dialog tag without defining a form. When form="true", the dialog creates its own form.

Here is a example I have tested:

**test.gsp:**

```
    <html>
        <head>
            ....
            <r:require modules="grailsui-dialog"/>    
        </head>
        <body class="yui-skin-sam">            
            <gui:dialog width="300px" 
               controller="test" 
               action="showTags" 
               params=" [id:userInstance.userId]" 
               form="true"                        <!-- the key to remote submit -->
               update="dialogData" 
               draggable="true" 
               triggers="[show:[type:'link', text:'Show Tags', on:'click']]" 
               modal="true" >    
               <!-- You can put any input element here, which will be submitted in the form-->
               <div id='dialogData'>This will be updated by the controller action....</div>   
           </gui:dialog>
       </body>
   </html>
```

**TestController:**

```
class TestController {

    def test() { 
        .........
    }

    def showTags() {
        def user = User.findByUserId(params.id)
        def tagInstanceList = user.tags
        render(template: "ajaxResponse", model: [tagInstanceList: tagInstanceList, user:user])          //render a template, not a view
    }
```

For an Ajax request, you can not render a view, which will replace the original page. Instead, you should send back a template with the tags you want to show in the dialog:

**_ajaxResponse.gsp**

```
<h3>Tag List of user ${user.username}</h3>
<g:each in="${tagInstanceList}" var="tag">
    <p>${tag}</p>
</g:each>
```

Comment: Jinzhao Wu, Thanks so much for trying to help me. I think, I didn't phrase my question correctly. What I am trying to accomplish is, I want to show the details of each record in the list in the popup window as the user click the link(something like, "Show details") in each record. In my case, each record in the list has tag_name, username,fullname,posted_date, etc. I want to show this detail in a popup window as the user clicks the link in each record(in the list). Thanks

Comment: Sure. You can do whatever you want just by change the code in your controller and gsp view accordingly. I think the issue here is to make the dialog work first.

Comment: I tried this code, it works for me. However, it shows the view (showTags) rendered output when I submit the form. In my case, I don't have any form. All I want to do is, just show the details of each record in the dialog as the user clicks the link in each record. Thanks so much.

Comment: Then you do not need the 'controller' and 'action' parameter, just put static data inside it.

Comment: Thanks,Jinzhao Wu. I tested it with static data, it works. I also want to show some related info (not part of the record in the list) in that dialog. That related info will come from a controller action. I want to show this related info also in the dialog while the user clicks the link in the record (in the list).

Comment: You can pass the related info from the controller action to this gsp view with operation like: `render(view:'thisOne', params:[data: data])` , and show this data in the gsp view using `${data}` or `${data.id}`.

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't work without the "form=true" attribute. Moreover, it only returns the related info from the controller action when I press the submit button, and also it replaces the record(in the list) details that already show up in the dialog. BTW, the syntax "params" doesn't work to return the Map in the controller action, instead I used "model". Thanks much.

Comment: I think I'm totally confused about your requirement. Can you show me the controller methods that render this gsp view and then receive the reqeust from it?

Comment: I updated my original posting with the controller actions. I want to somehow show the userInstanceList returned from the showTags action in the dialog window when the user click the "Show Tags" link. Thanks

Comment: @Mike, I got it. You should render a template instead of view in the second controller action. I've updated my answer according to your edit.

Comment: Jinzhao Wu, thanks for continue to help me. I tried this, but it doesn't work for me. I added "<div id="dialogData">      <g:render template="/user/ajaxResponse"/>
</div> in test.gsp to render the template(ajaxResponse) on the dialog. With this code, the page (test.gsp) gives me 500 error while loading. Without this code the test.gsp at least renders properly, but when I click the "Show Tags" link it shows the dialog, but not firing the controller action. If I add "form=true", then it fires the controller action while submitting the form, but gives 500 error again. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Follow my code first. The template is rendered from controller. Make sure you added _ajaxResponse.gsp in right place.

Comment: This is what I did, I replaced "<div id='dialogData'>This will be updated by the controller action....</div>" with this "<div id="dialogData"> <g:render template="ajaxResponse"/> </div>" and tried. I am not able to make this work. I now tried g:include to call the controller action. It works for me. However, not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: @Mike did you carefully go through my updated answer? The point is not to replace existing dialogData div as you did, but to modify last render operation in controller action as `render(template: "ajaxResponse"...)`, and add a new gsp file _ajaxResponse.gsp as I put there.

Comment: Yes I did create _ajaxResponse.gsp under "views/test" and also changed the render operation in the controller action like this:  def showTags() {
        def user = User.findByUserId(params.id)
        def tagInstanceList = user.tags
        render(template: "ajaxResponse", model: [tagInstanceList: tagInstanceList, user:user])         
    }  Thanks

Comment: Don't modify `<div id='dialogData'>This will be updated by the controller action....</div>`.

Comment: I tried this. It renders the template only when I use "form=true" and submit the form. Moreover, it doesn't render the template on the dialog window, it returns on test.gsp.

Comment: If you want the result to be rendered in the dialog, move `<div id='dialogData'>This will be updated by the controller action....</div>   ` into dialog. I updated my answer to show that. And `form=true` is necessary because you need the date from showTags() returned.

Comment: I agree. This will not work without "form=true". Since I need to get the related info(from showTags()) as the user clicks the "Show Tags" link(i.e. not using the form in the dialog), I am going to use g:include for now. I know, this is not the perfect solution. Because, it will call the controller action for every record as the view(test.gsp) is rendered. Thank you so much for trying to help me. Appreciate your help.